# footer showing up in wrong place on two pages(others are fine)

Tags: html, css, footer

My site's footer is showing up in the wrong place on my [contact page](http://frshstudio.com/contact/) and my [blog page](http://frshstudio.com/blog/). All of the other pages have the footer styled correctly and in the right location. What could be causing this/what's the best way to remedy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `clear:both` to `#footer` in your style sheet. That should do it.

Comment: ah, of course. thank you.
will accept answer as soon as the time limit expires.

Answer (score 0):

Put a clear:both on your footer element:

```
#footer {
clear: both;
}
```

The blog and sidebar divs are floated.  You need to clear out the floats on the footer for the footer to act "blocky".